# Selecting multiple checkboxes with Javascript verification

Tags: php, javascript, forms, checkbox

I'm writing a form whereby multiple checkboxes can be selected and saved into a MySQL database. However, I now want to limit the number of checkboxes a user can select using javascript, and have run into some trouble.

It seems for the import function to still work, each checkbox needs to have the same name as each other so they can be identified and imploded, however for the Javascript function to work each name needs to be different so that they can be differentiated.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received!

Here's the code that I've been playing around with.

Javascript function:

```
<?php $calc = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); ?>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">

function KeepCount() 
{
var NewCount = 0

<?php while($count_row = mysql_fetch_array($calc)){
echo "

if (document.import1.checkbox".$count_row['id'].".checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1}

";
} ?>

if (NewCount == 6)
{
alert('You can select up to 5 competitors. If you wish to import more you will need to add more judges.')
document.import1; return false;
}
} 
</SCRIPT>
```

Form:

```
<form action="import_process.php" method="post" name="import1" id="import1">
<input name="import" type="submit" id="import" value="Import">

<table>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Gender</td>
</tr>

<?php $counter = 1;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr bgcolor=white>";
echo "<td align=\"center\">
<input name=\"checkbox".$row['id']."\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox[]\" value=\"".$row['id']."\" onClick=\"return KeepCount()\"></td>";
}
echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['gender']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$counter++;
}
?>
</table>
</form>
```

import_process.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
$id = "('" . implode( "','", $checkbox ) . "');" ; 
$sql="
INSERT INTO..."
```

Comment: i cant understand what exactly you are trying here , what does the import.php do ?

Comment: The table displays a list of names & genders for people who are in a user's sports club. They select which people they want to enter as competitors into a competition. The import_process.php should identify the selected competitors ID and inserts theor details into a competition table. At least it should do, in the above example the JavaScript works but the import doesn't.

Comment: you mean you are not able to sent the information related to the selected competitors to your server , but your able to restrict user from checking 5 checkboxes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit difficult to understand your code, but i think you get confused by the difference of name an id. Id must be different in every checkbox, name must be the same:

```
<input id=\"checkbox".$row['id']."\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" value=\"".$row['id']."\" onClick=\"return KeepCount()\"></td>";
```

And the name-attribute is the one, wich needs the [], so you get the result in the array `$_POST['checkbox']`.

The second is, that your function KeepCount seems to check always the same checkbox (or I really don't understand how it works) because whatever `$count_row['id']` is, it's set once while the page is parsed so the javascript function cannot really count anything.

So change the checkbox-creation like this:

```
<input id=\"checkbox".$row['id']."\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" value=\"".$row['id']."\" onClick=\"return KeepCount(this)\"></td>";
```

and the javascript like this

```
var count = 0;    

function KeepCount(it) {
 if (it.checked) {
  count = count + 1;
 } else {
  count = count - 1;
 }
 if (count == 6) {
  alert('You can 
  etc.
```

That should work.

By the way: value=row['id'] seems to be nonsense too.

Comment: Thanks for that - the alerts come up as they should and the import function also works. The only thing is that after the alert comes up the user is still allowed to have more than the required number of checkboxes selected. I think I'm on the right lines by adding this but again it's not working perfectly:

Comment: var count = 0;
    function CountUp(it){
    if (it.checked){
    count = count + 1;
    } else {
    count = count - 1;
    }
    if (count == <?php echo ($quota+1) ;?>) {
    alert('You can select up to <?php echo $quota ; ?> competitors. If you wish to import more you will need to add more judges.')
    document.import1; return false;
    count = count - 1;
    }
    }

Comment: instead or additional to return false (wich has no concrete reason i could figure out) you put "it.checked = false" - that should help. Also: after the bracket of the alert a semicolon is missing.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much - having this on the side as a project means it doesn't get a lot of attention and so I'm not sure I'd have figured that out. Cheers!